# Number of lines in a file

Tags: windows, shell

I want to obtain the number of lines from file using the follow line command, but show the follow error:

Line command:

```
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< someFile.txt') do set /a lines=%%i print lines
```

Error:

```
%%i was unexpected at this time.
```

Can someone please tell me what is bad in the code, or maybe tell me other code for obtaining the number of lines from a file?

Comment: I think this is an english only forum. Creo que este forum es solo en ingles.

Comment: You have the reason. I has edit the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the superfluous `print lines` in that line it should work. Note however that you cannot execute that line directly on the command line. The `%` signs are doubled for use in a batch file. So wither put the following line in a batch file:

```
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< someFile.txt') do set /a lines=%%i
```

or execute the following line directly on the command line:

```
for /f %i in ('find /v /c "" ^< someFile.txt') do set /a lines=%i
```

And as Anders notes, the `/a` isn't *really* necessary. However, it won't break anything there. Your problem actually was that you tried executing the line on the command line directly. Removing the `/a` won't accomplish anything there.

Comment: This is correct answer with nice explanation. You helped me with similar problem. I wrote batch file to count all lines in files with specific extension and put it on [github](https://github.com/lu-ko/utils-windows/tree/master/file-line-counter)

Answer (score 0):

`set /a` is for math calculations (`set /a x=1+1`)

Just removing /a works for me:

```
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< someFile.txt') do set lines=%%i print lines
echo %lines%
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
find /v /c "Some text that won't be in any file" somefile.txt
```

Comment: Note that the OP wants the number in an environment variable; hence the `for` around it. Your variant gives a result to the screen and furthermore in a format that includes the file name, making it less suitable for extraction of the number of lines.